# How to use jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, image

I have written jQuery code, in files `Main.html` and `ajax.php`. The `ajax.php` file returns the link of images to `Main.html`.

Now in `Main.html`, I have Image1, Image2, Image3, etc.

My `Main.html` file:

```
<html>
    ...
    # ajax.php Call
    ...
    # Return fields from Ajax.php
</html>
```

My ajax.php file

```
echo "<a href='src1'><img src='src_path1' id='fid1' alt='Name1' /></a>Click To View image1\n";
echo "<a href='src2'><img src='src_path2' id='fid2' alt='Name2' /></a>Click To View image2\n";
// etc.
```

So, after executing ajax.php, I get the image locations in Main.html.

Now, when I click the Image1 link from Main.html, that corresponding image should display in the same window.

So I thought about whether again to use jQuery to view an image on the same page. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you post your actual jQuery code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File `ajax.php` output must return the below [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML):

```
<a href="#" class="imageLink" title="fid1"><img src="src1" id="fid1" alt="Name1" style="display:none;" /><span>Click To View image1</span></a> 
<a href="#" class="imageLink" title="fid2"><img src="src2" id="fid2" alt="Name2" style="display:none;" /><span>Click To View image2</span></a> 
<a href="#" class="imageLink" title="fid3"><img src="src3" id="fid3" alt="Name3" style="display:none;" /><span>Click To View image3</span></a>
```

And [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.imageLink").click(function(){
            $("#"+$(this).attr("title")).show();
        $(this).find("span").hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might want to take a look at the [jQuery lightbox plugin](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

Define this div in your html:

```
<div id="pictureframe"></div>
```

Now add an onclick handler on the image links to do the following:

```
$("#pictureframe").load(image_url);
```

You need to structure your code to easily retrieve the image_url.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Put a hidden div in your page that has an image (tag `img`):

```
<div id="imageDivisionHolder" style="disply:none;">
    <img id="imageItemHolder" src="" alt="" />
</div>
```

Set the class for all images that come from file `ajax.php` and put the big image source in an attribute of it. I put it in the `Title` attribute.

```
<img src='src_path1' id='fid1' alt='Name1' class='item' Title='src_path1_bigimage' />
```

And the jQuery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img.item").click(function(){
        $("#imageItemHolder").attr("src",$(this).attr("title"));
        $("#imageDivisionHolder").show();
    });
});
```

Or you can write a function that do it and set the onclick of images to run it. This way is not recommended.

Comment: Ata Will You Check my Error spot I done , I have Modified the code and still i have problem any Solution?

Comment: Hi venkatachalam, I read your answer again, but I can't understand that what's your problem. May you explain your answer more for me?

Comment: Yes Ata , The ajax.php has the following function
 1.echo "<img src="src1" alt="name1">
 2.echo "<img src="src2" alt=name2>

Yes its hidden by adding <display:none> while click the hyperlink that
corresponding image need to display ,Instead i used to click image to show that Image as you suggest